# Windows 10 still allows old password

Tags: authentication, passwords, windows

Desktop with Windows 10 (at home).

I changed my Windows password several days ago, restarted several times, and still *both* old and new passwords work.

How to make Windows *forget* the old password?

Comment: How did you change the password?

Comment: Log in with the old password. Run the command `WHOAMI` from the command prompt. Do the same logged in with the new password. [Edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: In a domain environment I see this when the password is changed offline. Log in with the old password, lock the device and then unlock it with the new password.

Comment: -) Changed using *desktop* :  Setting->Accounts->Your Info->Manage Microsoft account ...

-) It wasn't off-line, as the password did change in the cellular skype etc.

-) Now (almost a week after) it is ok i.e. old password is ignored.

-) Noticed a similar behaviour last time. 

Odd guess : Windows wants to avoid the issue of getting-locked-out-right-after-password-change, so it allows the old password to work for a few days 
But if I shared my password with someone, and what to stop it, it is not immediate. ( i.e. he will be able to access for a few days).

That behaviour is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Some say it will accept the old password until you first log in with the new one.

For me, this did the trick:

> If you have changed your password through live.com (aka outlook.com)
>   and it isn't synchronized with your local Windows account, do the
>   following:
>
> - Open a command prompt and type: runas /u:[my account]@outlook.com cmd.exe   *replace [my account] here with your own username - change
>     @outlook.com to whatever domain your MS account uses
> - Type your new MS account password and hit Enter
>
> The above steps will synchronize your Microsoft password to your local
>   machine. This worked for me as I had the same issue reported here.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-still-accepting-my-old-password-at/c0d78132-77e9-4f2e-9b9c-06db1639117c)

After this the old password is not working any more.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. This issue has been nagging me for years and I've been remembering my last 3 or 4 Microsoft Account passwords just to log into Windows 10 machines. SMH